# Restore AWS RDS from xtrabackup through CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cloudformation, database-backups, percona

maybe someone could help me.

I have Aurora cluster CloudFormation template ang I'm trying to restore database data from xtrabackup. 
I can use this backup through GUI - AWS provide button "Restore Aurora DB cluster from S3". I think, I can do it through CLI, but I need restore this backup from CloudFormation. I found option DBSnapshotIdentifier, but, as I understand, this option works just with RDS Snapshots.

Do we have a way to do it?

Or, maybe I can restore this backup to exist RDS Cluster.

Comment: Look at this and might help you. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html

Comment: Yes, thank you, I looked at this,
I see just DBSnapshotIdentifier oprion and it requires ARN of snapshot. I haven't snapshot, I have database backup on S3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take the backup you used and turn it into an AWS snapshot, so then you can reference it. While AWS Console does this for you it seems that CloudFormation doesn't offer that facility.